# Button not working for jquery events in firefox

Tags: jquery, html, firefox

this cross browser thing is making me crazy. i have the following markup for every button element on page.

```
<button type="button" id="btn-cart-3939" title="Add to Cart" class="button">
    <span pro-id="3939" class="prod-cart-reduce" style="display:none;">-</span>
    <span class="btn-cart" max-qty="4" pro-id="3939">
        <span class="prod-cart-qty">+</span>
        <span>Add to Cart</span>
    </span>
</button>
```

and the corresponding code in jquery for add to cart is:

```
jQ('.btn-cart').click(function(){
    var maxQty = parseInt(jQ(this).attr('max-qty'));
    var currQty = jQ(this).children().first().text();
    if(jQuery.inArray( '+', currQty )!=(-1)){
        var id = jQ(this).attr('pro-id');
        spill2('product_addtocart_form_'+id);
        jQ(this).children().first().text('1').fadeIn();
        jQ(this).siblings().css({'display':''});
    }
    else{
        currQty = parseInt(currQty);
        if(currQty === maxQty){
            var k = jQ(alertBox).clone().addClass('alertBox');
            jQ('body').append(jQ(k));
            jQ('.alertBox #alert-message').html('Sorry, WE have limited stock of this item.');
            jQ('.alertBox').css({margin:'0 5%'}, function(){}).delay(2000).fadeOut('slow', function(){jQ(this).remove()});
        }
        else{
            var id = jQ(this).attr('pro-id');
            spill2('product_addtocart_form_'+id);
            currQty = currQty + 1;
            jQ(this).children().first().text(currQty).fadeIn();
        }           
    }
```

Now, this code works like a charm in chrome, but in firefox, nothing is happening, and no errors in firebug either. One more thing is, all other jquery code is working fine in firefox too.
Can anyone tell me, what terrible mistake i'm doing here?
Much thanks in advance.

---

P.S. One more thing, when i remove the type attribute from button element, it starts throwing 2 events, unnecessary excecution of the last else part.

Comment: Is you JS wrapped in document ready? http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: Well no, I thought i didn't need to, as it is a click event handler. Is it necessary for click event handlers too.

Comment: yes, its a good practice to add your code in `document.ready({function()})`, because it fires when `DOM` is ready. Only, then you have an element to bind handlers.

Comment: depends on where the script is placed... is it placed after the target element or before.... but to be in safer side it is better to put it in a dom ready handler

Comment: Ok, i put the js in `jQ(document).ready(function(){});` as well but with no success. And my script is placed at the very end of the file.

Comment: Creating a fiddle will help a lot...

Comment: Sorry i'm not sure about creating a fiddle for this one will help, as it's working in chrome browser but not in firefox browser.

Comment: I edited my question to provide some further help regarding the question, please take a look.

Comment: Ok, I had to get rid of buttons, to make it work. But still searching for reason why it didn't work. Browsed through a hell lot of forums, couldn't get what's wrong.

Comment: hook the event to the button not to the span.

Comment: @Holybreath, I need two different responses from the same button, that's why I can't hook the event to the span. Is this behavour really because of this? I'm a little surprised.